# Use SpreadAllocate in cross-contract calling

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

I'm trying to call an erc20 contract from another custom erc20 contract.

Both, the original contract and calling contract have the following macros:

```
#[ink(storage)]
#[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
```

In the calling contract's struct, we have `asset: Erc20Ref,`, and facing this error:

```
the trait bound `Erc20Ref: SpreadAllocate` is not satisfied
the trait `SpreadAllocate` is not implemented for `Erc20Ref`
```

The Erc20Ref is generated by ink, and I guess it doesn't implement SpreadAllocate. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

It is a duplicate of this [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1149). You can find a workaround there. Soon it will be fixed with [storage refactoring](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1134).